# Error al firmar app con codesign en Mac OS

Tags: macos, certificado-apple

Los pongo en contexto, en mi empresa contamos con una cuenta de desarrolladores en Apple, queremos firmar nuestra aplicación fuera de Xcode, ya contamos con los certificados de Developer ID Application y el Developer ID Installer. Pero cuando el ejecuto el comando codesign me da el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vi que en el KeyChain el certificado de Developer ID Application no cuenta con una llave privada [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], esto puede estar relacionado con el problema?

Muchas gracias por la 
ayuda, no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre este tema. :)

Comment: Se firma con la llave privada. Sin llave privada no es posible firmar.

Comment: Sería bueno que copiaras el texto del error, pues la imagen es pequeñita.

Comment: El error es: the specified item could not be found in the keychain

Comment: Ya tengo la llave privada de mi certificado, pero me da el mismo error